# How can use UIView on top of collectionView, so that when i scroll cells, UIView should not move?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am creating horizontal carousel using collectionView Cells and I want to apply one custom view which has label on it on top of the collectionView, so that when i scroll cells the UIView should remain but changing the text of the label and cells should change. Please help me..

Comment: Add the view as a sibling to the collection view?

Comment: How can I add as a sibling, because rootcontroller is UICollectionViewController?

Comment: Don't use a UICollectionViewController. Use UIViewController.

Comment: You can change the root view controller to a classic `UIViewController`, which embeds both the carousel and the collection view. You can use child controllers to keep the collection view controller.

Comment: thanks for your attention. I started that project with all UICollectionViewControllers. I need to change whole code. if there is alternative way, please help me

Comment: I don't know it may help you or not. But you can try to create a UIView programmatically.

Comment: I just create every ui programatically for the sake of convenience... thank you

Comment: I don't think using UIViewController instead of UICollectionViewController will require lots of changes.

Comment: I am newbie and doing intern. If it is possible, help to understand the concept with some example...

Answer (score 1):

Hope This is What you are expecting.

[image]

Did everything programmatically for demo purpose. this is how `CollectionViewController` and the whole code looks like.

```
//
//  SliderController.swift
//  AssignmentSO
//
//  Created by Chanaka Caldera on 7/5/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 StackOverflow. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class SliderController: UICollectionViewController {

    var topview: UIView!
    var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //MARK: - set up top view and label
        topview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100))
        topview.backgroundColor = .green
        view.addSubview(topview)

        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100))
        label.text = "Title 0.0"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
        topview.addSubview(label)


        // MARK: - Registering the cell and set EdgeInsets (if you are using storyboard set EdgeInset would be enough
        self.collectionView!.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        self.collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true

    }
}

// MARK: Datasource
extension SliderController {

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return 5
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.label.text = "Cell \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
}

extension SliderController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 100
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
}

extension SliderController {
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let xvalue = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

        let cellIndex = xvalue/width

        switch cellIndex {
        case 0:
            label.text = "Title \(cellIndex)"
        case 1:
            label.text = "Title \(cellIndex)"
        case 2:
            label.text = "Title \(cellIndex)"
        case 3:
            label.text = "Title \(cellIndex)"
        case 4:
            label.text = "Title \(cellIndex)"
        default:
            label.text = ""
        }
    }
}


//MARK: Custom cell
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    var label: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .lightGray
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentView.bounds.size.width, height: contentView.bounds.size.height))
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
        label.text = "2"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        addSubview(label)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

hope this will help to someone and did every thing on same file for demo purpose. sorry for that. cheers!

Comment: Yeah exactly brother. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can load `UIView()` in `collectionView` section header like below.

Create Header Xib with class type `UICollectionReusableView`

[image]

Register Xib that you just created

```
collectionFeatured.register(TodaySectionHeader.nib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "TodaySectionHeader")
```

`CollectionView` `Delegate` and `DataSource`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 80)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "TodaySectionHeader", for: indexPath) as! TodaySectionHeader
    sectionHeader.labelDate.text = Date().toString(format: "EEEE dd MMMM").uppercased()
    sectionHeader.labelTitle.text = "Today"
    return sectionHeader
}
```

If you want to stick that header on top now you have to set `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` during collection initialization where you set `delegate` `datasource` and register `xib` basically in `viewDidLoad`

```
let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout // casting is required because UICollectionViewLayout doesn't offer header pin. Its feature of UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout?.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
```

Comment: thank you,   appreciated, but i was using the header part as menu bar like(home, profile, etc..) and and at indexPath.row 0 i wanted to implement my custom carousel collectionView in a separate collectionViewController. the thing is i want o fix my UIView on 0th cell of the collectionView

Comment: Please share more details and code in question so i will try to help you

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much. Can i send it by email. because it is a bunch of code and impossible here to share?